# Aborting JSF Ajax Request from jsf.ajax.addOnEvent()

Tags: ajax, jsf, jsf-2

I would like to have a central place where I monitor ajax requests and in certain situations abort them.

The only thing I don't know to do is to actually abort the ajax request from one central function.

I Imagine that the solution would look something like this:

```
jsf.ajax.addOnEvent(function(data) { 
    if (data.status === 'begin') {
        // abort the ajax request
    }
});
```

But I might be mistaken.

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not possible by the standard [JSF JS API](http://javaserverfaces.java.net/nonav/docs/2.0/jsdocs/index.html). Your best bet is to add an `onclick` or `onchange` handler on the calling JSF component which returns `false` if the desired condition is met to abort the ajax request.

```
<h:commandButton onclick="return mayFireAjax(this)">
    <f:ajax />
</h:commandButton>
```

You can if necessary abstract this away with [`jQuery.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) (or [`jQuery.delegate()`](http://api.jquery.com/delegate/) or [`jQuery.live()`](http://api.jquery.com/live/) depending on the jQuery version used) on a common selector so that you don't need to repeat it on every desired component.

```
$(someSelector).on("click", function() {
    return mayFireAjax(this);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have control the source, you can always attach a onClick to the UICommand component. But in some situation, you do not have access to source. For example, the ajax is provided by some third-party component. You do not want to mess up with their components.

First, I have a small js library.

```
var FxJSFBegin = "JSFBegin";

if (jsf) {

    var originalRequest = jsf.ajax.request;

    jsf.ajax.request = function(source, oevent, options) {

        var event = $.Event(FxJSFBegin);

        event.options = options;

        event.originalEvent = oevent;

        $(source).trigger(event);

        if (event.isDefaultPrevented()) {

            return;

        } else {

            originalRequest.apply(null, arguments);

        }

    };

}
```

This piece code proxies original JSF ajax call. It uses jQuery to fire a "JSFBegin" event. Integration code can listen this event using jQuery mechanism. Listener can cancel the jsf call using event.preventDefault().

Requirement:

1. jQuery
2. This piece code should be placed after jsf.js is loaded.

Answer (score -1):

Using global="false" will help you prevent calling the ajax status for an ajax call. Please refer to the following link.

[Different Ajax statuses for different components in PrimeFaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11789153/different-ajax-statuses-for-different-components-in-primefaces/11789300#11789300?newreg=7728dc4c5f924d6aa1d52520b8448afc)